# Why does Outlook require a password twice when adding an account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords

When adding an account to Outlook, the dialog makes you enter your account password, then re-enter it.

[image: Add Account Dialog]

Why is this? The re-type password idea is used when *creating* an account to make sure you don't have a typo and create a password you don't know. What purpose does it serve to ask someone for their password twice for an *existing* account? If they enter the password wrong, the authentication will fail and they'll just be prompted to enter it again.